# flickr style image upload using html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, filereader

i am trying to make an image upload gallery using html5 canvas . I am trying to resize the images at the client side and show the preview . but when i upload multiple images with big size like 5mb each , the browser halts and sometimes crashes . I checked on flickr so their system instantly resize the uploaded images without any load to browser no matter how many pictures i upload . moreover my thumbnails when resized give the poor quality and whatever if i do something to make a make it better , the load on my browser shoots up . Here is my code for the images preview and resize

```
$(document).ready(function() { 


if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
    document.getElementById('getfiles').onchange = function(){
        var files = document.getElementById('getfiles').files;
        for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            resizeAndUpload(files[i]);
        }
    };
} else {
    alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.');
}

function resizeAndUpload(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function() {

    var tempImg = new Image();
    tempImg.src = reader.result;
    tempImg.onload = function() {

        var MAX_WIDTH = 220;
        var MAX_HEIGHT = 120;
        var tempW = tempImg.width;
        var tempH = tempImg.height;
        if (tempW > tempH) {
            if (tempW > MAX_WIDTH) {
               tempH *= MAX_WIDTH / tempW;
               tempW = MAX_WIDTH;
            }
        } else {
            if (tempH > MAX_HEIGHT) {
               tempW *= MAX_HEIGHT / tempH;
               tempH = MAX_HEIGHT;
            }
        }

        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = tempW;
        canvas.height = tempH;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, tempW, tempH);
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");


        var newImgs = new Image();
                newImgs.src = dataURL;

                document.body.appendChild(newImgs);


      }

   }
   reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the "browser halts and sometimes crashes" part of your troubles...

Make sure you give the images time to load using .onload:

```
var newImgs=new Image();
newImgs.onload=function(){
    document.body.appendChild(newImgs);
}
newImgs.src=dataURL;
```

And note that the .onload should be declared before .src

So, put .onload before .src on your tempImg also.

```
var tempImg = new Image();
tempImg.onload = function() {     
    ...
}
tempImg.src = reader.result;
```

As far as the poor quality when up-sizing thumbnails, that's unavoidable.

You thumbnail only has a small pixel resolution and up-sizing will always create poor results.

Comment: sorry but the halt and crashing problem is because of the file reader api . i've checked that much . I tried what you said but that didn't work . Any other solution ?